# Punctuation before "and"

Tags: punctuation

What would be the proper placement of commas before "and" in this situation?

I think that A, B, C and D are useful qualities and will help her complete the assignment.

Comment: This is a stylistic argument.  As @brandonjsmith points out it is known as the Oxford comma.

Answer (score 0):

See this article on the Oxfors, or serial comma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma .

The comma is obligatory when separating clauses, but not in other cases.